# Transition in Animations not working in Angular

Tags: angular

I have a main list and sub list panel in my Angular project. I need to animate the sub list to fold down / fold up when clicking on a main list item. I have created this:

component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { trigger,state,style,transition,animate,group } from '@angular/animations';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-category',
  templateUrl: './category.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./../../resources/css/style.css'],
  animations: [
        trigger('subcat', [
        state('show', style({
            display: 'block',
        })),
        state('hide', style({
            display: 'none',
        })),
        transition('show <=> hide', animate('100ms ease-out'))
    ])
  ]
})

export class CategoryComponent implements OnInit {

  show: boolean = false;

  state: string = 'hide';

  constructor(){}

  showlist() {
        this.state = (this.state === 'hide' ? 'show' : 'hide');
  }

  ngOnInit(){

  }

}
```

component.html:

```
<div class="category">
   <div class="row">
          <dl *ngFor="let item of array">
            <dt *ngIf="post.parent_id=='0';then m" id="itemcat" style="width: 15px"></dt>
            <ng-template #m><dt (click)="showlist()" ><a [routerLink]="[/list]" routerLinkActive="active">{{post.name}}</a></dt>
                <dl *ngFor="let subitem of array">
                <dt *ngIf="sub.parent_id==post.id;then s"></dt>
                <ng-template #s><dd  [@subcat]='state' ><a routerLink="/sublist" routerLinkActive="active">{{sub.name}}</a></dd></ng-template>
                </dl>
            </ng-template>
          </dl>
   </div>
</div>
```

when I click on a main item, it will show sub items list but not animated. Just show and hide the sub list. And also Show all the sub lists when clicking on any of main list item instead showing the particular sub list only. How can solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're actually not animating anything and the only css property you used (`display` cannot be animated. You need somethingg like :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-category',
  templateUrl: './category.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./../../resources/css/style.css'],
  animations: [
        trigger('subcat', [
        state('show', style({
            translate: translateY(0); // or height: '*' or ...
            opacity: 1;
        })),
        state('hide', style({
            translate: translateY(-100%); // or height: '0' or ...
            opacity: 0
        })),
        transition('show <=> hide', animate('100ms ease-out'))
    ])
  ]
})
```